# Using Vue to count up by seconds

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a small timer Vue component. A user needs to be able to start and stop that timer. Here's my component thus far:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a class="u-link-white" href="#" @click="toggleTimer">
            {{ time }}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['order'],
        data() {
            return {
                time: this.order.time_to_complete,
                isRunning: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleTimer() {
                var interval = setInterval(this.incrementTime, 1000);
                if (this.isRunning) {
                    //debugger
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    console.log('timer stops');
                } else {
                    console.log('timer starts');
                }
                this.isRunning = (this.isRunning ? false : true);
            },
            incrementTime() {
                this.time = parseInt(this.time) + 1;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm toggling the `isRunning` variable to determine whether the timer is running or not. On first click (the play), the timer begins and increments successfully.

However, on the second click (the pause), the `isRunning` var toggles back to off, but `clearInterval(this.incrementTime)` is not clearing the interval and pausing the timer. When I insert that debugger, and manually hit `clearInterval(interval)` via the console, it returns undefined.

Does anybody have any insight on how I've formatted my component incorrectly?

Comment: You'll need to store the value returned from `setInterval` somewhere. Right now, you declare a variable for it, but that goes out of scope as soon as the function ends. You'll want something like `this.interval = setInterval(...)` and `clearInterval(this.interval)`. Also, don't create the interval every time; just create it when it's not running and clear it when it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a working example covering the concepts I mentioned in the comment above. This is not an exact implementation of your component, just an example to show you how it could work.

```js
console.clear()
new Vue({
  el: "div",
  data() {
    return {
      time: 0,
      isRunning: false,
      interval: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTimer() {
      if (this.isRunning) {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
        console.log('timer stops');
      } else {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.incrementTime, 1000);
      }
      this.isRunning = !this.isRunning
    },
    incrementTime() {
      this.time = parseInt(this.time) + 1;
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="u-link-white" href="#" @click="toggleTimer">
    {{ time }}
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a class="u-link-white" href="#" @click="toggleTimer">
            {{ time }}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['order'],
        data() {
            return {
                time: this.order.time_to_complete,
                isRunning: false,
                interval: undefined // store the interval here
            }
        },
        methods: {
            toggleTimer() {

                if (this.isRunning) {
                    clearInterval(this.interval);
                    console.log('timer stops');
                } else {
                    this.interval = setInterval(this.incrementTime, 1000);
                    console.log('timer starts');
                }
                this.isRunning = !this.isRunning; // better to read
            },
            incrementTime() {
                this.time = parseInt(this.time) + 1;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Without further testing i think that your first interval just never stops because the pointer to it is just in function scope.
Thats why i removed interval into the data object, because so it is available when the methoded gets called the second time.
I hope it helps